# add an element to a list inside a list in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following variable on my state:

this.state = {

```
        playerList: {
            player: [
                {
                    playerAlias: [
                        {
                            name: null
                        }
                    ],
                    idPlayer: null,
                    playerName: null,
                    broadcastChannel: null,
                    clusterName: null
                }
            ]
        }

    }
```

I want to add a playerAlias to my playerAlias List,and I did this method:

```
insertAliasToList = () => {
    let insertedAlias = {
        name: this.state.newAlias
    }

    this.setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        playerList: {
            ...prevState.playerList,
            player: {
                ...prevState.playerList.player,


                playerAlias: [...prevState.playerList.player.playerAlias, insertedAlias]


            }
        }
    }))

}
```

However,this error occurs:
Uncaught TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using object syntax for an array. In this line:

```
playerAlias: [...prevState.playerList.player.playerAlias, insertedAlias]
```

`prevState.playerList.player` is an *array*, so you can't use dot notation on it. If you want to add a new player alias to the **first** player, you'd have to specify that with index notation:

```
playerAlias: [...prevState.playerList.player[0].playerAlias, insertedAlias]
```